# Lambda with no argument works in VB but not in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda, delegates

In VB I can do this:

```vb
Dim a = New Action(Of String)(
        Sub()
            Debug.Print("Hello World.")
        End Sub)
```

But in C# I cannot do this, which makes sense to me because the lambda definition *should* match delegate:

```
var a = new Action<string>(() => 
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Hello World.");
});
```

I **can't** do this in VB, which makes sense.

```vb
Dim a = New Action(
        Sub(x As String)
            Debug.Print("Hello World.")
        End Sub)
```

So why does VB allow that one aberrant case where you can provide a lambda expression that takes no arguments but which is seemingly not compatible with the delegate?

Comment: Is `Options Strict` On?

Comment: @JohnSaunders -- Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Relaxed Delegate Conversion (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531336.aspx)

> Relaxed delegate conversion enables you to assign subs and functions
> to delegates or handlers even when their signatures are not identical.
> Therefore, binding to delegates becomes consistent with the binding
> already allowed for method invocations.
>
> (...)
>
> **Relaxed delegates also allow you to completely omit parameter specifications in the assigned method:**

It also describes why that might be helpful:

> The ability to omit parameters is helpful in a situation such as
> defining an event handler, where several complex parameters are
> involved. The arguments to some event handlers are not used. Instead,
> the handler directly accesses the state of the control on which the
> event is registered, and ignores the arguments. Relaxed delegates
> allow you to omit the arguments in such declarations when no
> ambiguities result. In the following example, the fully specified
> method OnClick can be rewritten as RelaxedOnClick.

Comment: An anonymous delegate allows you to omit all parameters, like `new Action<string>(delegate {})`.

Comment: @vcsjones Nice! Thanks for pointing that out. Statement removed.